# How to hide the popup using jquery?

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller

i have two  popup, in popup1, if i filled all textboxes and proceed,i will be redirected to popup2. otherwise, i should stay in popup1 with the validation message.

Note:If my "caseNum" had valid value i will redirected to popup2 otherwise to popup1.

i have my code like,

```
function NewCaseForm()//popup1
{
var OwnerAgency = $("#OwnerAgency :selected").val();
var OwnerAgent = $("#OwnerAgent :selected").val();
 var NewCase =
 {
        "OwnerAgency": OwnerAgency,
        "OwnerAgent": OwnerAgent,
       };
$.ajax({
    url: '/Index/NewCase/',
    data: JSON.stringify(NewCase),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: "POST",
    success: function (caseNum) {
        if (caseNum) {
            var caseNo = caseNum;
            ImportTypeSelectionNewCase(caseNum);//popup2
        }
    },
});
```

}
  have my controller like,

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewCase(NewCase model)
    {
  if (model.MyCaseNumber == null || model.OwnerAgency.ToString() == "" || model.OwnerAgent.ToString() == ""
                || model.AnalystAgency.ToString() == "" || model.AnalystAgent.ToString() == "")
            {
                model.IsValid = true;
                model.ValidationMessage = "Please Enter a New Case Number or Analyst information or Owner information to continue.";
                return View(model);
            }
            else
           {
              int caseId = _ServiceHelper.SaveNewCase(
                    model.OwnerAgency, model.OwnerAgent, );
                string caseNum = model.MyCaseNumber.Replace(" ", "_").Trim()                         + ":" + caseId;
                return Json(caseNum);
                }
           return View("ImportTypeSelection");
```

But my code does like, instead of showing in popup1 its showing popup2.As iam the beginner i dont know how to resolve this. Kindly tell me.

Comment: what is the value of caseNum did you debugged the value

Comment: k then how do you know that  its not valid

Comment: so if its not valid then caseNum  is null right, then change your if condlition like if(caseNum!=null){....}

Comment: your "if" always trigger if there is any value  that's why the 2nd  popup comes .edit the success function and post your controller method

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment , so putting as answer...

1. Please alert the value of caseNum and check what is returned
2. try making you ajax query synchronous async:false;

Comment: this may sound like being stupid ..but did you try if(caseNum == 12345) ? just focus if it will work when value is 12345 all other condition can be fixed later..Also by default ajax query is asynchronous ie it will not wait for answer before forwarding with next statement execution .. if you put async:false; it will make sure that only after answer is received next statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

change your controller like this

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewCase(NewCase model)
    {
  if (model.MyCaseNumber == null || model.OwnerAgency.ToString() == "" || model.OwnerAgent.ToString() == ""
                || model.AnalystAgency.ToString() == "" || model.AnalystAgent.ToString() == "")
            {
                return View("");
            }
            else
           {
              int caseId = _ServiceHelper.SaveNewCase(
                    model.OwnerAgency, model.OwnerAgent, );
                string caseNum = model.MyCaseNumber.Replace(" ", "_").Trim()                         + ":" + caseId;
                return Json(caseNum);
                }
           return View("ImportTypeSelection");
}
```

and your client side function like this

```
        function NewCaseForm()//popup1
        {
        var OwnerAgency = $("#OwnerAgency :selected").val();
        var OwnerAgent = $("#OwnerAgent :selected").val();
         var NewCase =
         {
                "OwnerAgency": OwnerAgency,
                "OwnerAgent": OwnerAgent,
               };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Index/NewCase/',
            data: JSON.stringify(NewCase),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (caseNum) {
                if (caseNum !="") {
                    var caseNo = caseNum;
                    ImportTypeSelectionNewCase(caseNum);//popup2
                }
    else{
     var errorMessageOne="error 1";
 var errorMessageTwo="error 2";
 var errorMessageThree="error 3";
 var errorMessageFour="error 4";

//and use these values 

    }
            }
        });
```

from now the if only trigger casenum is not an empty string.. and use jsonresult insted of action result if you are in the same page

Comment: :Thanks. But this will not suits  to my question. i have more than two validation msg inside my code.Then what will i do in that case?